# One time donation using bitcoin from creditcard or bank-account

Tags: exchanges, donation

How would I go about making a one-time donation in bitcoin if I don't want a get a bitcoin-wallet?

Think about getting money from an ATM abroad, the money is in my account in currency A, but I get it in currency B from the machine. Is there anyplace I can change euros for bitcoin and pay them to someone else in one step?

The question was asked before but the answer is not valid anymore, the company named in that answer (https://www.litebit.eu/) does trading.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend it, but you probably can. Upon withdrawal from an exchange, you will be asked to provide a deposit address to send the funds to. If you give the address of who/whatever you want to donate to, the funds will go there.

As for what exchange to use, such advice is off-topic on this site.

Comment: Why is this not recommended?